# image doesnt fit parent element

Tags: html, css

image doesnt fit parent element
here is the full code 
 https://jsfiddle.net/601q9j7c/1/

```html
<section class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-data">
      <div clas="bgimg"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/10/16/45/home-office-595476_960_720.jpg" alt=""> </div>
      <div class="cardDetails">
        <span class="date"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>  March 30, 2020 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-data">
      <h1 class="title">Vuestic – Free Vue Admin Template</h1>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium ullam ratione id nihil quis officia voluptas vitae molestiae provident natus exercitationem, praesentium maiores quo quas ducimus. Voluptatibus debitis ea perferendis?</p>
      <div class="cta">
        <a href="#"> Read more &rarr;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Percentage width to every tag will only give you distorted elements. Define width of parent elements and then give the image tag `max-width:100%`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set any defined width in either the CSS or the `<img>` tag, the image will be displayed at full size regardless of its container. This is your issue. So you need to ensure the image is at maximum 100% of it's parent's width.

## HTML only

```html
<section class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-data">
      <div clas="bgimg"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/10/16/45/home-office-595476_960_720.jpg" alt="" width="100%"> </div>
      <div class="cardDetails">
        <span class="date"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>  March 30, 2020 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-data">
      <h1 class="title">Vuestic – Free Vue Admin Template</h1>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium ullam ratione id nihil quis officia voluptas vitae molestiae provident natus exercitationem, praesentium maiores quo quas ducimus. Voluptatibus debitis ea perferendis?</p>
      <div class="cta">
        <a href="#"> Read more &rarr;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

It is best practise to do this with CSS rather than directly into HTML, but you have not shown any CSS in your question.

A CSS example is below:

## CSS example

```css
.bgimg > img {
     max-width: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     height:auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-data">
      <div class="bgimg"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/10/16/45/home-office-595476_960_720.jpg" alt=""> </div>
      <div class="cardDetails">
        <span class="date"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>  March 30, 2020 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-data">
      <h1 class="title">Vuestic – Free Vue Admin Template</h1>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium ullam ratione id nihil quis officia voluptas vitae molestiae provident natus exercitationem, praesentium maiores quo quas ducimus. Voluptatibus debitis ea perferendis?</p>
      <div class="cta">
        <a href="#"> Read more &rarr;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all ! your spelling your *class* is wrong, that's why image is not fitting.
Make the *width of the image to be 100%* and its *height is auto* so that is don't stretch but then your image may be come out of parent container make there **overflow:hidden**

```css
.cards {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    }
                    .card {
                        width: 60%;
                       justify-content: center;
                        display: grid;
                        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
                        box-shadow: 10px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
                        height: 25rem;
                    }
                    .img-data {
                        height: 100%;
                        z-index: 1;
                        background-color: salmon;
                        display: grid;
                        grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
                    }
                    .bgimg {
                      overflow: hidden;
                    }
                    .bgimg img {
                       height: auto;
                       width: 100%;
                    }
```

```html
<section class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-data">
      <div class="bgimg"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/10/16/45/home-office-595476_960_720.jpg" alt=""> </div>
      <div class="cardDetails">
        <span class="date"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>  March 30, 2020 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-data">
      <h1 class="title">Vuestic – Free Vue Admin Template</h1>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium ullam ratione id nihil quis officia voluptas vitae molestiae provident natus exercitationem, praesentium maiores quo quas ducimus. Voluptatibus debitis ea perferendis?</p>
      <div class="cta">
        <a href="#"> Read more &rarr;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If width is 100% of its container then there is no need for "overflow:hidden"

Comment: I need to do this because it was overflowing the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

This should work and is dynamic:

This gives the image an inherited width and height, which means that it replicates the width of the previous object. It is given with the property `style="width: inherit; height: inherit;"`

```css
.bgimg {
  width: 500px; /*Or whatever you want...*/
}
/* this CSS can be directly inserted in a tag with style="width: 500px;"*/
```

```html
<section class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-data">
      <div class="bgimg"><!--*NOTE: you wrote <div clas="bgimg">(you missed an 's')--><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/10/16/45/home-office-595476_960_720.jpg" alt="" style="width: inherit; height: inherit;"> </div>
      <div class="cardDetails">
        <span class="date"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>  March 30, 2020 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-data">
      <h1 class="title">Vuestic – Free Vue Admin Template</h1>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium ullam ratione id nihil quis officia voluptas vitae molestiae provident natus exercitationem, praesentium maiores quo quas ducimus. Voluptatibus debitis ea perferendis?</p>
      <div class="cta">
        <a href="#"> Read more &rarr;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps!